# Trouble understanding Elasticsearch Scroll documentation

Tags: python, elasticsearch

So I'm using Python 3.8 and Requests lib to help me do RESTful API calls to ES 7.4.2. Looking at the ES documentation for [Scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll) it states:

*the initial search request should specify the scroll parameter in the query string, which tells Elasticsearch how long it should keep the “search context” alive*

So here is the first call I make.

```
requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:9200/paulk/_search?scroll=1m, headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'}, data=json.dumps({"size": 100, "query": {"match_all": {}}}))
```

This returns a 200 and everything is expected, but. Acording to the documentationf or the second and final call it states:

*The result from the above request includes a _scroll_id, which should be passed to the scroll API in order to retrieve the next batch of results.*

So I do the next 3 steps as in the documentation which I arrive at the following:

```
requests.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search/scroll", headers=headers, data=json.dumps({"scroll": "1m", "scroll_id": scroll_id}))
```

But the result I get is a 400, What am I doing wrong? The return string I get back is:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Failed to parse request body"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Failed to parse request body","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unrecognized token 'scroll': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@a7e638b; line: 1, column: 8]"}},"status":400}
```

I have tried a few different combinations but all I ever get back is a 400.

Comment: You are not json encoding the data in the second call. Use `json=` instead of `data=`.

Comment: I didnt paste in the right part, I have tried json encoding and still returns a 400